# "Значения каких" или "значения которых"

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

> - В следующей таблице указано, значения каких из свойств наследуются самостоятельно, а каких из них — нет.
> - В следующей таблице указано, значения которых из свойств наследуются самостоятельно, а которых из них — нет.

Какой из вариантов является правильным?

В устной речи мне привычней использовать слово "каких", но если задуматься, оно подразумевает описание объекта по некоторым свойствам (велосипед какой? зеленый, спортивный), а не описание его с точки зрения принадлежности к некоторой группе (ты купил велосипед? да, который ты мне советовал).

И слово "которых" поэтому уместней. Прав ли я?

Comment: Если задуматься, то мы все предпочтем "Какой из вариантов является правильным?", хотя точнее будет "Который из вариантов является правильным?". Почему сложилось такое "странное" предпочтение, какие у него объективные причины? Тут надо посмотреть на ситуацию в английском с which of

Comment: А что здесь "значения свойств"? Каким образом _различные_ свойства оцениваются _количественно_ - нулем или единицей ("самостоятельно / не самостоятельно")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отвечать коротко, то **нет**: вне конкретизирующего контекста более уместно "значения каких из свойств" или просто "значения каких свойств". Обычно "который" = "какой из уже названных, рассматриваемых и т. п.". Вариант замены "каких" на "которых" обозначает выбор из нескольких *оговоренных* вариантов. При этом множественное число ("которых") подразумевает, что оговаривалась и возможность выбора *не единственного* свойства, что требует специфического контекста, к которому возможна столь конкретная отсылка, например:

> Ровно два из рассмотренных нами пяти свойств наследуют значения
> самостоятельно, в отличие от остальных трех. В следующей таблице указано, значения которых из
> свойств наследуются самостоятельно, а которых из них — нет.

Соответственно, *вне контекста* ваш первый вариант ("каких из") уместнее, поскольку никакая информация не теряется и нет косвенной отсылки к неясным (не оговоренным) ограничениям выбора.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы в том, что «каких» буквально обозначает «какие характеристики», а «который» выделяет объект из некой совокупности. Но правильное использование слов — общесогласованное использование. Если люди массово используют слово «какой» в значении выделения из совокупности, если они при этом понимают друг друга, то такое использование слова — правильное.